# How to share an array through two HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to know how to share an array through two HTML files.
I have two HTML files and I want to share an array between them.
I point out array because for this, I can't use `localStorage` because it is an array, and I can't use `split()` because my array has objects in it:

```
var examplearray = [
 {first: "Nice!", second: "Wonderful!"},
 {first: "Wow!", "Amazing"}
]
```

I tried linking both of the HTML files to one javascript file, and put the variable there, and `alert()` the variable to test, but it didn't work. Please show me if there is a way tp share an array between two HTML files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: @Sujit It might but I don't understand it.

Comment: Could you share the rest of your code especially the alert() part?

Comment: I think what you want to know is not how to share an array through several html files but how to manipulate objects in an array.

Comment: just use json to convert array to string and back

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two scripts tag to your HTML file. One for JavaScript file to export the array and the other for importing this array to other JavaScript file.

So your HTML file must content this structure:

```html
<script src="/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/importing.js"></script>
```

And your JavaScript file which is exporting the array must contain this statement:

```js
export const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Finally the other JavaScript file which will import the array must contain this statement in top level of the file:

```js
import array from '/file/path/exporting.js'
```

Comment: what is the "<script src="/exporting.js"></script>" for? Also, what is the "/file/path" for in "import array from '/file/path/exporting.js'"?

Comment: These are examples.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array of objects, use an object of objects. Example:

```js
var exampleObject = {
    0: {first: "Nice!", second: "Wonderful!"},
    1: {first: "Wow!", second: "Amazing!"}
};
```

This will pretty much work like an array. To get the first object, you do `exampleObject[0];`

---

An object can be converted to a string and back to an object whenever you need it.

To convert an object to a string, use `JSON.stringify()`. Example:

```js
var stringObject = JSON.stringify(exampleObject);
```

This string can then be stored in your `localStorage` like this:

```js
localStorage.setItem('exampleObject', JSON.stringify(exampleObject));
```

To convert the string back to an object, use `JSON.parse()`. Example:

```js
var myObject = JSON.parse(stringObject);
```

So, you get the object from your `localStorage` like this:

```js
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('exampleObject'));
```